# Add different copy of codebase to existing git repository

Tags: git, github

I recently took over a project which has a Git repository hosted on GitHub and is running on a production server.
However, the code on the server was not cloned from the repo, does not have a .git file, and is different from the code in the repository.

What I would like to do is add the production code to the existing repo as a new branch. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... However, the code on the server was **not cloned** from the repo, does not have a .git file, and is different from the code in the repository
>
> What I would like to do is add the production code to the existing repo as a new branch.

Its pretty simple.

On your server inside your code folder make it a git project

```
# convert the folder to a git repository
git init

# commit your local changes to a new branch
git checkout -b <branch name>
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Now once its a git repo add a remote to the repository. git can have multiple remotes.

```
# add the repository URL
git remote add origin <git hub url>

# "download" all changes from the repository
git fetch --all --prune
```

At this point you have all your changes in local branch and you have all the original repo code on your file system. Now you have to combine the 2

```
# choose the desired branch
git branch -a

# merge the desired branch code into your branch.
# since its unrelated history you can simply merge it you have
# to use cherry-pick
git rev-list --reverse master | git cherry-pick -n --stdin
```

In my case i have conflicts which you will also have since you worked on the original code. Fix those conflicts and commit and you are ready to go.

[image][image]